# How to create a table that calculates percent change between values in two separate tables in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, formattable

I have two data tables, each representing the monthly spread in one year and the same in the next.

I would like to calculate the % change in values based on my index ('Category Name') so each row value reperesnets the % change from the first year to the next.

Reference the first years table below:

```
`Category Name`   Oct   Nov   Dec   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep  Average `Percent Total`
   <fct>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 Salty Snacks    36340 43950 34246 26758 36151 51390 35299 43337 35251 32449 46309 33534 37918.             39.4 
 2 Candy           23003 23814 19271 14269 21902 30986 22054 27269 22651 20789 30090 21632 23144.             24.0 
 3 Nutrition Bar   10563 12182  9657  7029 10740 15392 10926 14955 12370 10914 16130 11945 11900.             12.4 
 4 Cookies         10751 11679  9051  6752  9416 14467 10993 14364 12207 11066 14862  9656 11272              11.7 
 5 Nuts/Trailmix    4018  4371  3512  2676  3935  5586  3820  5182  4555  3869  5672  3938  4261.              4.43
 6 Pastry           3531  4328  3666  2853  3906  5396  3521  4318  3571  3520  4830  4026  3956.              4.11
 7 Meat Sticks      2131  2669  1919  1575  2156  3021  2088  2630  2369  2043  2759  2091  2288.              2.38
 8 Other            1500  2191  2133  1650  2151  2696  1196  1169   760   751   954   747  1492.              1.55
 9 Crackers            1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    13    39    86    23    13.5             0.01
10 Food                0     0     0     0     0     2     7     3    15    25    30     9     7.58            0.01
```

And here is the next years table, same layout/parameters:

```
`Category Name`   Oct   Nov   Dec   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep Average `Percent Total`
   <fct>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 Salty Snacks    35562 38043 37697 33079 31942 35862 35646 43987 33551 34916 46172 35511 36831.            39.1 
 2 Candy           22722 21071 20496 17663 19470 21834 21924 26846 21046 22482 29402 22477 22286.            23.6 
 3 Nutrition Bar   12339 12975 12073 10668 11813 12999 12897 17062 12982 13506 17234 13033 13298.            14.1 
 4 Cookies         10042  9712  9489  7820  8472  9936  9756 11867  9307  9525 12123  9544  9799.            10.4 
 5 Pastry           5322  5243  5185  4518  4546  4868  4819  5792  4275  4484  5547  4486  4924.             5.23
 6 Nuts/Trailmix    4236  4279  4034  3656  3733  4364  4171  5514  4209  4486  5595  4409  4390.             4.66
 7 Meat Sticks      2067  2195  2024  2085  2068  2236  2342  2814  2337  2311  3028  2428  2328.             2.47
 8 Crackers           12     4     2     1     0    49   185   459   355   550   839   705   263.             0.28
 9 Other             433   177    89    38    28    17     9     4     2     0     1     1    66.6            0.07
10 Food                4     0     5     2     0     0    11    46    48    65   121    77    31.6            0.03
```

I am trying to create a new table that shows % change for each month for each Category (Salty snacks, Candy, etc.). My plan is take this and create a formattable from it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, you can arrange, the rows in `df2` based on `df1` and then perform the calculation.

```
df2 <- df2[match(df1$Category_Name, df2$Category_Name), ]
cbind(df1[1], round((df2[2:13] - df1[2:13])/df1[2:13] * 100, 2))
```

---

Or using `dplyr` and `tidyr` you can convert the data to long format, join them perform the calculation and convert the data to wide format again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  select(-Average, -Percent_Total) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Category_Name) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>%
  select(-Average, -Percent_Total) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Category_Name), by = c("Category_Name", "name")) %>%
  mutate(change = (value.y - value.x)/value.x * 100) %>%
  select(-value.x, -value.y) %>%
  mutate(change = na_if(change, Inf)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = change)


# A tibble: 10 x 13
#   Category_Name     Oct    Nov    Dec   Jan    Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep
#   <fct>           <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Salty_Snacks    -2.14 -13.4   10.1   23.6 -11.6   -30.2    0.983    1.50   -4.82    7.60  -0.296    5.90
# 2 Candy           -1.22 -11.5    6.36  23.8 -11.1   -29.5   -0.589   -1.55   -7.09    8.14  -2.29     3.91
# 3 Nutrition_Bar   16.8    6.51  25.0   51.8   9.99  -15.5   18.0     14.1     4.95   23.7    6.84     9.11
# 4 Cookies         -6.59 -16.8    4.84  15.8 -10.0   -31.3  -11.3    -17.4   -23.8   -13.9  -18.4     -1.16
# 5 Nuts/Trailmix    5.43  -2.10  14.9   36.6  -5.13  -21.9    9.19     6.41   -7.60   15.9   -1.36    12.0 
# 6 Pastry          50.7   21.1   41.4   58.4  16.4    -9.79  36.9     34.1    19.7    27.4   14.8     11.4 
# 7 Meat_Sticks     -3.00 -17.8    5.47  32.4  -4.08  -26.0   12.2      7.00   -1.35   13.1    9.75    16.1 
# 8 Other          -71.1  -91.9  -95.8  -97.7 -98.7   -99.4  -99.2    -99.7   -99.7  -100    -99.9    -99.9 
# 9 Crackers      1100     NA     NA     NA   NaN      NA     NA       NA    2631.   1310.   876.    2965.  
#10 Food            NA    NaN     NA     NA   NaN    -100     57.1   1433.    220.    160    303.     756.
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Category_Name = structure(c(10L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 
9L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Candy", "Cookies", "Crackers", 
"Food", "Meat_Sticks", "Nutrition_Bar", "Nuts/Trailmix", "Other", 
"Pastry", "Salty_Snacks"), class = "factor"), Oct = c(36340L, 
23003L, 10563L, 10751L, 4018L, 3531L, 2131L, 1500L, 1L, 0L), 
Nov = c(43950L, 23814L, 12182L, 11679L, 4371L, 4328L, 2669L, 
2191L, 0L, 0L), Dec = c(34246L, 19271L, 9657L, 9051L, 3512L, 
3666L, 1919L, 2133L, 0L, 0L), Jan = c(26758L, 14269L, 7029L, 
6752L, 2676L, 2853L, 1575L, 1650L, 0L, 0L), Feb = c(36151L, 
21902L, 10740L, 9416L, 3935L, 3906L, 2156L, 2151L, 0L, 0L
), Mar = c(51390L, 30986L, 15392L, 14467L, 5586L, 5396L, 
3021L, 2696L, 0L, 2L), Apr = c(35299L, 22054L, 10926L, 10993L, 
3820L, 3521L, 2088L, 1196L, 0L, 7L), May = c(43337L, 27269L, 
14955L, 14364L, 5182L, 4318L, 2630L, 1169L, 0L, 3L), Jun = c(35251L, 
22651L, 12370L, 12207L, 4555L, 3571L, 2369L, 760L, 13L, 15L
), Jul = c(32449L, 20789L, 10914L, 11066L, 3869L, 3520L, 
2043L, 751L, 39L, 25L), Aug = c(46309L, 30090L, 16130L, 14862L, 
5672L, 4830L, 2759L, 954L, 86L, 30L), Sep = c(33534L, 21632L, 
11945L, 9656L, 3938L, 4026L, 2091L, 747L, 23L, 9L), Average = c(37918, 
23144, 11900, 11272, 4261, 3956, 2288, 1492, 13.5, 7.58), 
Percent_Total = c(39.4, 24, 12.4, 11.7, 4.43, 4.11, 2.38, 
1.55, 0.01, 0.01)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

df2 <- structure(list(Category_Name = structure(c(10L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 
7L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 4L), .Label = c("Candy", "Cookies", "Crackers", 
"Food", "Meat_Sticks", "Nutrition_Bar", "Nuts/Trailmix", "Other", 
"Pastry", "Salty_Snacks"), class = "factor"), Oct = c(35562L, 
22722L, 12339L, 10042L, 5322L, 4236L, 2067L, 12L, 433L, 4L), 
Nov = c(38043L, 21071L, 12975L, 9712L, 5243L, 4279L, 2195L, 
4L, 177L, 0L), Dec = c(37697L, 20496L, 12073L, 9489L, 5185L, 
4034L, 2024L, 2L, 89L, 5L), Jan = c(33079L, 17663L, 10668L, 
7820L, 4518L, 3656L, 2085L, 1L, 38L, 2L), Feb = c(31942L, 
19470L, 11813L, 8472L, 4546L, 3733L, 2068L, 0L, 28L, 0L), 
Mar = c(35862L, 21834L, 12999L, 9936L, 4868L, 4364L, 2236L, 
49L, 17L, 0L), Apr = c(35646L, 21924L, 12897L, 9756L, 4819L, 
4171L, 2342L, 185L, 9L, 11L), May = c(43987L, 26846L, 17062L, 
11867L, 5792L, 5514L, 2814L, 459L, 4L, 46L), Jun = c(33551L, 
21046L, 12982L, 9307L, 4275L, 4209L, 2337L, 355L, 2L, 48L
), Jul = c(34916L, 22482L, 13506L, 9525L, 4484L, 4486L, 2311L, 
550L, 0L, 65L), Aug = c(46172L, 29402L, 17234L, 12123L, 5547L, 
5595L, 3028L, 839L, 1L, 121L), Sep = c(35511L, 22477L, 13033L, 
9544L, 4486L, 4409L, 2428L, 705L, 1L, 77L), Average = c(36831, 
22286, 13298, 9799, 4924, 4390, 2328, 263, 66.6, 31.6), Percent_Total = c(39.1, 
23.6, 14.1, 10.4, 5.23, 4.66, 2.47, 0.28, 0.07, 0.03)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: @Ronak Shah Thank you! This worked great. Do you have any idea how to set the +numbers green and the -numbers red in the table? I am using formattable.

Comment: @Dinho Sorry, I am not aware of `formattable`. Maybe you can ask a new question for that.